# Qt equivalent of gtk.SizeGroup

Tags: qt, gtk, pygtk

I'm migrating a large pygtk project to replace gtk usage with qt. One problem which has come up is there is a lot of usage of gtk.SizeGroup, what is the best way to replicate that behaviour when using Qt?

Comment: I've to admit that I always considered `GtkSizeGroup` as strange vehicle. There is nothing like this in Qt (that I'm knowing about). You may develop your own QLayout to achieve this. I believe it is easier to re-design your GUI a bit. Can't this be done by a `QGridLayout instead` (or nested boxes)?

Comment: We use them when there are rows and each have a label and we want the lables all to be the same size. There can be gaps where some elements are not part of the size group, then lower down the dialog we want the same size group to be used again.